# Circle menu for mapview Marker in Android google maps API V2

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-android-api-2, android-mapview

I'm looking to create a circle menu for markers in my app that uses Google maps.
I've found this online example of what I am trying to do:http://demo-ee.com/index.php/examples/view/circle-menu-for-marker-with-mx-google-maps-for-expressionengine# 
The problem is that this is for google maps in a webview, I'm looking to do this on Android.
Does anyone know if this is possible to achieve with google maps for Android and if it is, how much work would be involved to do it?
Is it possible to rebuild this example code in java to use in an Android app?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put this as an answer and not as a comment, but I don't think you can achieve the same.

First of all, on android you don't have the "hover" callback for maps, you can only use the onMarkerClick listener.
You could try to build a custom infowindow (there are a few tutorial online but never followed, so I can't give you a trusted one, you have to try :( ) and check if the iw can be placed around your item. Unfortunately on android there is a limited set of functionalities, but to be honest, I would explore a different UX for that (cards, dialogfragment or other).

Check how google maps behaves when clicking on a place (a view scrollable from bottom with details).
You can also think about using a toolbar/expandingtoolbar